# receiving error: 'Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' while using npm

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, npm

I am using npm v1.0.104/node 0.6.12 on ubuntu - I am receiving the error copied below while attempting to install any new modules via npm (I tested socket.io earlier using http, not https though & am wondering if that could have resulted in the issue with npm/unsigned certs).  The error pops up once npm tries to resolve the 'https://registry.npmjs.org' URL.  Is there anyway I can ignore the error or perhaps locate/add the cert to a trusted store in order to continue using npm.

Any insight on what needs to be done to resolve the issue will be appreciated (I would prefer to resolve the issue through configuration as opposed to re-installing if possible).

> Error: "Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"

Full Message:

```
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:252:28)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1150:24)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:375:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:734:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:130:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-13-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "jed"
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.104
```

Comment: Dont remove strict SSL.

Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16534065

Comment: **As of February 27, 2014 npm no longer supports its self-signed certificates.** Please see [npm's blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more) or the recent answer below for more information.

Comment: In case you're having trouble with this on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, a solution is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096459/self-signed-cert-in-chain-error-on-elastic-beanstalk-for-nodejs/22097926?noredirect=1#22097926

Comment: **nolim1t**: this does not address the cause of the issue, and **Kevin**: the commands in the blog post are incomplete.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22099006/106302 for commands that worked for me.

Comment: @ali PLEASE change the 'Accepted answer' This issue is appearing because of an npm upgrade, and not an issue with SSL. Turning off SSL is BAD, and especially since the currently correct response is to update npm.  The answer by Kevin Reilly should be the Accepted answer. Thank You.

Comment: Was unable to publish for a week. Answers that I found only pointed to the possibility that the server was having issues. This was driving me mad.

Comment: npm conf set strict-ssl false
is working for me

Comment: Forgive me for being blunt, but the choice to use SSL or not is not your concern. There are use cases where this is unavoidable and a workaround is necessary. It is up to the developer/admin to make the decision to ignore the SSL issues or not. They take the risks you do not take, they have information you do not have.

Answer (score 604, accepted):

Running the following helped resolve the issue:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I cannot comment on whether it will cause any other issues at this point in time.

Comment: run "npm config set ca null" instead, ignoring ssl errors is a bad idea

Comment: I don't like the idea of ignoring SSL errors, nor do I like the idea of destroying the ca that npm comes with. As far as I know, no sensitive information is being sent to npm so there should be no negative repercussions from changing the registry url from https to http.

Comment: @SnowInferno SSL also guarantees that you are talking to the real registry.npmjs.org . Someone could potentially install malicious packages.

Comment: @adotout I'm stuck in an environment that is production only, no dev, no test, no staging, just production. We're running Node v0.6.14 and are constantly going from project to project with zero down time between in which to spin up a dev environment, fire up our app in node v0.10.x, figure out what's now broken and fix it. I don't like the idea of destroying something that was shipped with the version of npm (the ca setting) to bypass the issue and I refuse to turn on a setting that ignores ssl errors. The likelihood of someone hijacking the non-ssl site but not the ssl site are quite low imo.

Comment: @SnowInferno Their website doesn't have to be hijacked at all, it could be your router/your dns/anything in between your server and their server. Anyone could be redirecting the traffic and serving you malicious packages. I'm just trying to say "there should be no negative repercussions from changing the registry url from https to http" is not a true statement. I'm not saying ignoring the warning or overwriting the CA are any better options. I ended up updating my version of node to fix the issue.

Comment: Please don't ignore ssl issues, as the error is there for a very good reason. Also, a bit of searching resulted in the following tweet, which links to the official solution to your problem (update npm): https://twitter.com/npmjs/status/439279809307242496

Comment: Don't disable SSL.  These commands worked for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22099006/106302

Comment: Will `npm config set strict-ssl true` undo it?

Comment: My issue was caused by a proxy that I'm behind, "npm config set ca null" and 'npm config set ca ""' still gave me the same error, but removing SSL worked perfectly. Sometimes good practice isn't as important as what actually works.

Comment: @Squirrl, yes it should. to verify you could run npm config get strict-ssl

Comment: @djechlin - Evil? Yes.  Sometimes one evil is less than another.  My System Admins do an "Approved Man in the Middle" attack on the whole company.  This lets me use NPM despite their self signed certificate.

Comment: @Vaccano and now you're vulnerable to attacks from anyone.

Comment: @djechlin - very true.  Guess that is the trade off my System Admins have made for the company so they can be more secure in their knowledge of what everyone is doing on SSL sites.

Comment: +1, works! There is no any other way if you're behind corporate network with its own certificates in chain. Some companies forcing their own encryption via [Blue Coat](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/135378/11825), but at the same time forcing users to do desperate steps and disabling SSL to install required dependencies.

Comment: My client does a man-in-the-middle that renders the above problem. My workaround was to 'npm config set strict-ssl false' then do my nmp magic and finally 'npm config set strict-ssl true' to set records straight again. I is not my preferred solution but will do as a compromise. Well... the security is compromised already so compromise is a good to use for this context.

Comment: Disabling security is an inherently bad idea. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 238):

**As of February 27, 2014, [npm no longer supports its self-signed certificates](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more).** The following options, as recommended by npm, is to do one of the following:

**Upgrade your version of npm**

```
npm install npm -g --ca=""
```

-- OR --

**Tell your current version of npm to use known registrars**

```
npm config set ca ""
```

**Update:** npm has posted [More help with SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN and npm](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78165272245/more-help-with-self-signed-cert-in-chain-and-npm) with more solutions particular to different environments

---

You may or may not need to prepend `sudo` to the recommendations.

---

## Other options

It seems that people are having issues using npm's recommendations, so here are some other potential solutions.

**Upgrade Node itself**
Receiving this error may suggest you have an older version of node, which naturally comes with an older version of npm. One solution is to upgrade your version of Node. This is likely the best option as it brings you up to date and fixes existing bugs and vulnerabilities.

The process here depends on how you've installed Node, your operating system, and otherwise.

**Update npm**
Being that you probably got here while trying to `install` a package, it is possible that `npm install npm -g` might fail with the same error. If this is the case, use `update` instead. As suggested by Nisanth Sojan:

```
npm update npm -g
```

**Update npm alternative**
One way around the underlying issue is to use known registrars, install, and then stop using known registrars. As suggested by jnylen:

```
npm config set ca ""
npm install npm -g
npm config delete ca
```

Comment: Easiest solution is probably to download the latest version of Nodejs itself, it includes a new version of npm where this issue is resolved. None of the commands above worked for me.

Comment: I go with this solution since it's the first one not ignoring ssl (by either setting the check to false in config or using http instead). Thanks!

Comment: npm install npm -g also gives me the error SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Comment: I have the same problem as Anders Bornholm, so no dice with updating the npm

Comment: Also the same problem as Anders Bornholm. And I just installed nodejs through brew.

Comment: If this doesn't work, do `npm config set ca ""` first, then upgrade, then undo the config change.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22099006/106302

Comment: Do we need `sudo` for `-g`?

Comment: @Redsandro `sudo` changes the user, `-g` flag sets if to install globally for that user or just in local `node_modules`.

Comment: I updated node itself using ```sudo n stable``` and it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: `npm update` failed silently doing nothing, outputting nothing, as they say in the source now, use `npm install -g --ca ""`

Comment: On Windows, my version of Node was quite old (1.2.18) and I got stuck while self-updating npm due to a semver version (^2.2.1) mismatch. Just ended up installing the latest Node package and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 80):

For now I just switched registry URL from https to http. Like this:

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. I didn't want to lose the original CA or force it to ignore SSL errors.

Comment: Disabling security can't be the solution!

Comment: I had previously used this, but for some reason switching it back to 'https://' from 'http://' made mine work again.

Comment: After trying all other solution, this work for me finally :-)

Comment: I didn't want to turn off the checking of certs completely so tried this one. Worked but I have the same concern, so now we're pulling packages on an unsecured connection. I understand that this has nothing to do with Node, this is the problem I'm getting because of our proxy but still ... kind of crazy

Comment: That is causing an issue with my intranet firewall auth portal. See [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647828/398728): I had to remove this settings with `npm config rm registry` and use `npm set strict-ssl false` instead.

Answer (score 53):

The error `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` means that you have self signed certificate in certificate chain which is basically not trusted by the system.

If that happens, basically something fishy is going on, therefore as people already commented, it is not recommended to just disable certificate checks, but better approach is to understand what is the problem and fix the cause of it.

This maybe related either to:

- custom repository address which doesn't have the right certificate,
- a corporate network with transparent proxy.

  If you're behind a corporate web proxy, you should set-up the proper `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables or set them via `npm`:

  ```
    npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
    npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
  ```

  See: [How to setup Node.js and Npm behind a corporate web proxy](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)

If you trust the host, you can export the self-signed certificate from the chain and import them into system, so they're marked as trusted.

This can be achieved by checking the certificates by (change `example.com` into npm repo which is failing based on the `npm-debug.log`):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 < /dev/null
```

then save the certificate content (between `BEGIN` and `END`) into `.crt` file in order to import it.

### Linux

As per [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm/35510347?noredirect=1#comment79116054_35510347), you can add the below to the `/etc/environment` file (Node 7.4+) to export your CA chain, like:

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/yourCer‌​ts.pem
```

#### CentOS

On CentOS 5 this can be appended into `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` file, e.g.

```
ex +'g/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' <(echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443) -scq | sudo tee -a /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sudo update-ca-trust force-enable
sudo update-ca-trust extract
npm install
```

<sup>Note: To export only first certificate, remove `g` at the beginning.</sup>

In CentOS 6, the certificate file can be copied to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`.

#### Ubuntu/Debian

In Ubuntu/Debian, copy CRT file into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`  then run:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

### macOS

In macOS you can run:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/foo.crt
```

### Windows

In Windows: `certutil -addstore -f "ROOT" new-root-certificate.crt`

---

See also: [npm - Troubleshooting - SSL Error](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#ssl-error)

Comment: > If that's the case, you need to export the self-signed certificate from the chain and import them into system, so they're marked as trusted.

- Makes trick for me.

Comment: Great! It also helps to add NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/yourCerts.pem to the /etc/environment.

Node 7.4+ takes this into account

Comment: This is the only correct answer here. The rest is just an unsafe workaround...

Comment: @ph4r05 I did the same with ~/.zshrc on Mac: `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path-to-cert/yourCerts.pem`

Answer (score 50):

```
npm config set strict-ssl false -g
```

To save it globally

Comment: Doing this gives me the infamous `cb() never called!` npm error

Comment: After this setting, I'm geeting below error 
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Negotiate, NTLM

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\BuildAgent\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-24T10_23_46_563Z-debug.log

Comment: Disabling security is an inherently bad idea. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 31):

You need to upgrade npm.

```
// Do this first, or the upgrade will fail
npm config set ca ""

npm install npm -g

// Undo the previous config change
npm config delete ca
```

You may need to prefix those commands with `sudo`.

Source: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg: re. your edit: on OS X I don't think `sudo` is required at all, and only prefixing the upgrade command with `sudo` worked fine for me.  YMMV.

Comment: Ah, this worked for me. Thanks for the specific instructions on undoing the config change (so I didn't have to dig it up myself)!

Comment: Interesting. I only made the edit after having tested this on a Debian server. I like the current revision though ;)

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian require additional linking, see my answer below.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. This does not disable security and is the "official" solution desribed in npm blog.

Comment: This works regardless. My setup is Ubuntu 13.10. I used NVM to install node (and the NPM version it came with). NPM version was 1.4.3 when i ran into this issue. Followed the instructions in this answer and all went well. Thanks jnylen.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're on an older version of node (such as Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) then upgrading npm like this will break it.

Comment: `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS ` is very helpful!

Answer (score 23):

Putting this before the command seems to work `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`.
ex: `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm ...`

It would be best to figure out how to make node see self signed certificate as valid.  strict-ssl suggestion above didn't work for me for some reason.  If you understand the security implications and need a temporary quick fix, this is what I found in some [random github issues](https://github.com/apigee/microgateway-core/issues/9#issuecomment-248728735) during Google search of the error.

Comment: for Windows, use "set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0". And then works like a charm !!

Comment: It works :) `Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.`

Answer (score 9):

just for development in windows

```
$Env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Comment: just a small detail - this is a script to run from Powershell console. And then run "npm i" within the same PowerShell window.

Answer (score 8):

The repository no longer supports self-signed certificates. You need to upgrade `npm`.

```
// Disable the certificate temporarily in order to do the upgrade
npm config set ca ""

// Upgrade npm. -g (global) means you need root permissions; be root 
// or prepend `sudo`
sudo npm install npm -g

// Undo the previous config change
npm config delete ca

// For Ubuntu/Debian-sid/Mint, node package is renamed to nodejs which 
// npm cannot find. Fix this:
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

You need to open a new terminal session in order to use the updated `npm`.

**Source:** This was originally an edit on **jnylen**'s answer. Although the guidelines say *"We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial,"* the edit was rejected due to *"This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost."* I guess the community prefers a separate answer.

Comment: This worked for me. However I didn't need the last command: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`.

Comment: It probably depends on whether you installed from the official Ubuntu repositories, a third party repository (for a newer version), or compiled yourself (for newest version).

Answer (score 8):

I've created an article how to disable most npm problems behind a corporate firewall if you're out of options.

Be aware that you might be vulnerable to attacks.

https://wnderlvst.com/stories/102a237a-cea1-463b-89db-82224f1c1cbe

Powershell

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false
yarn config set "network-timeout" 600000
$env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who on a **mac** with the same issue and installed npm via **homebrew**:

```
brew uninstall npm
```

then

```
brew install npm
```

Works for me on osx (10.9.1)

**EDIT**: You may need to `brew update` before installing npm. You can also do a `brew upgrade` after updating homebrew.  Also it might be helpful to run `brew doctor` if you run into any other issues.

Comment: can we install brew on window ?

Answer (score 5):

For people who are **struggling with getting a ca-file**:

1. Go to https://registry.npmjs.org/
2. Open the used certificate: [image]

3. Click Details, then export and save it as a (*.pem, *.crt) file

4. Then add this file to npm config `npm config set cafile "C:\Users\YOU\nameOfCert.crt"`

Hope this saves someone of you some minutes/hours :)

Comment: This is the solution that helped in my situation. We have a local Artifactory instance that uses a certificate from an internal CA. Even if the CA certificate was installed on the system, npm didn't work. I had to use the `npm config set cafile` command to set our CA certificate for npm, and then things worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Quick and clean solution (linux tested) (After fatidic February 27, 2014)**

---

**Uninstall npm**

```
npm rm npm -g
```

**Install npm** (new URL is *www.npmjs.org* instead *npmjs.org*)

```
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

**Tip**: how to install node.js in linux https://stackoverflow.com/a/22099363/333061

Comment: The command doesn't work anymore due to a redirect 301 but you can still type ```https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh``` in your browser and download it before running it manually.

Comment: Or run curl with the [-L flag](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT)

Comment: previous `curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh` command is redirecting to `https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh` that's why `curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` works seamless. is OK to install from now on little padawan. :)

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall NPM and install it again.

As of February 27, 2014 npm no longer supports its self-signed certificates.
http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more

The link above suggests upgrading NPM using NPM. This also fails with SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN...

Answer (score 2):

Turning off SSL seems like a profoundly bad idea. [npm's blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more) explains that they no longer support their self-signed cert. They suggest upgrading npm via `npm install npm -g`, but I of course got the same SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error. So I just updated node, which updated npm along with it. Exact procedure depends on how you installed node in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find the proxy details of your company and the npm registry that you should be using.
After that you can specify the same in .npmrc file located under user folder C:/users/<your_user>.

this is how it can be specified -

```
registry=https://your_company/npm/registry/
proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port/
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port/
```

The password is in plain text which is obviously not ideal may be there is a way to encrypt it in a way that npm understands.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes antivirus software can cause this issue. In my case, Kaspersky was the problem. I paused protection and it worked. If you're experiencing this, ask your antivirus support for help.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a super simple solution. All I needed to do was set the https-proxy in npm via `npm config set https-proxy "http://proxyserverurl:port"`. @somshivam 's solution works too, but if you're going to have the module installed by a cloud pipeline like Azure DevOps, you can't have the proxy setting in the npmrc file or it will fail.

Comment: How to fix this in Auzre DevOps? 
npm config set https-proxy "http://proxyserverurl:port this didn't work for me, still same error.

Comment: Can you share exact error and what you are doing when you receive it? For me this was an issue only on local (as Azure DevOps VM is not going through the corporate proxy). If you are receiving this error while running the DevOps pipeline it may be a different issue. Happy to help here but you may want to create a new SO Question instead of trying to address through these comments.

Answer (score -1):

I bypass this error with:

```
const https = require('https')

const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
})
```

In request, I pass:

```
httpsAgent: agent,
```

like:

```
await axios.get(options.url, {
    httpsAgent: agent,
    headers: options.headers,
    data: options.data
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I was having the same SSL self signed cert error because of corporate proxy. I was having issue while installing node-gyp. I tried uninstalling Angular/cli first and installing node-gyp and then try reinstalling Angular cli

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

It worked perfectly