# npm node enconding

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I want to npm install the following validate .json

```
{
    "name": "node-todo",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Simple todo application",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.4.4",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.2"
    }, 
    "private": true
}
```

but the npm install doesn't seem to work because I even cant npm install a sample json from
http://package-json-validator.com/

I installed npm and nodejs with the following commands

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Now I want to use npm install but the shell gives me this
    npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
    npm ERR! Failed to parse json
    npm ERR! Unexpected token /
    npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
    npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
    npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

```
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm using Sublime and saved the json as a UTF-8 (without the BOM tag)

Comment: well i tried this at the beginning, but didn't work for me either.

Comment: Sorry about removing my comment :) It didn't work with the exact same reason? I have no issues whatsoever with the official installer (or to run your `package.json`). Did you check `npm-debug.log` to see for any additional clues?

Comment: ah it worked now, i save UTF-8 without BOM in the false directory

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are running ubuntu or that you are using the aptitude package manager

```
apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get install nodejs
apt-get install npm
```

Then run this when needed to update the sources.list and install the latest version.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade nodejs
```

If you want to downgrade node simply use

```
apt-get install nodejs={version number}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Linux Installation - node.js**:

- Via package manager for many distros:
  https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

  Or
- Via download binaries (this worked for me after many problems with other solutions)

  a) download from https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/
  b) move to /usr/local/

  Note: To avoid permissions problems when install none modules globally (npm install -g ...) you must to move files preserving your ownership.

  > i) Unpack as normal user, ie, **not sudo**:
  >   tar -zxvf node-package.tar.gz
  >
  > ii) Move properly (-p same as -**preserve**=mode,ownership,timestamps):
  >   sudo cp -rp node-package/* /usr/local/ && rm -rf node-package

[image]

**Linux Installation - npm**

- Be sure you have node.js already installed (node -v):

  > curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  >
  > Note: *www.npmjs.org/install.sh* is the new URL after February 2014