# SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error on Elastic Beanstalk for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm well aware of the root of this issue, as `npm` wrote on their blog: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more

The solution is to either:

> 1) upgrade your version of npm
>
> `npm install npm -g`
>
> or
>
> 2) tell your current version of npm to use known registrars
>
> `npm config set ca ""`

However, neither of these solution work on Elastic Beanstalk. `npm`is linked to the version of node installed (v0.10.10), and it is not possible to tell the current npm version to use known registrars.

I run a 64-bit Amazon Linux instance for NodeJS

Adding this command in `.ebextensions` does not help:

```
container_commands:
  01_npm-fix:
    command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.10-linux-x64/bin/npm config set ca ""
```

Anyone as figured out a solution for this?

Comment: it is possible to edit ~/.npmrc, right?

Comment: Well it doesn't fix anything, I'm still getting that error, when trying to push a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way to make it work:

Put this in `.ebextensions`:

```
commands:
  01_enable_rootaccess:
    command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
  02_no-cert:
    command: sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.10-linux-x64/bin/npm config set ca ""
```

Worked like a charm in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well. Fix: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb32a4b053fe121b0b03. When applied in `container_commands` `npm install` has already run.

Comment: This solution worked for me (w/ Node v0.10.21).  Obviously not an advisable long-term solution, but works as a stop-gap on our dev server until Elastic Beanstalk supports a more recent version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue today. I fixed it by setting my global npmrc file, as follows:

```
02_no-cert:
  command: "rm -rf /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64/etc && mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64/etc && echo 'ca = ' > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64/etc/npmrc"
  ignoreErrors: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, didn't work for me. Amazon gave me a different version, that has not worked either:

commands:
  01-command:
    command: '$(find /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/*/bin | grep "npm$" | head -n1) config set ca ""'

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me either.

What I did find: at the time that the "commands" block is run, the node-install folder is empty. I assume this is because the commands run before node + npm is fully deployed to the bare instance.

I will try and test this assumption later today, and provide further feedback.