# Bower Install Error

Tags: node.js, bower-install

While Installing Bower, I am getting following Error :-

```
Stack trace:
Error: Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/es5-shim failed: SELF_SIG
NED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
    at createError (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bow
er\node_modules\bower-registry-client\lib\util\createError.js:2:15)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\lib\lookup.js:98:29)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\b
ower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\node_modules\request\request.js:129:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Request.request.emit (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\node_modules\request-replay\index
.js:69:33)
    at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\node_modules\req
uest\request.js:239:10)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1389:19)

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:74:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\bower\bin\bower:114:22)
    at Logger.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bow
er\node_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
    at C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\comman
ds\install.js:35:16
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\q\q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bo
wer\node_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at C:\Users\Rishabh.Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\q\q.js:557:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.1
Node version: 0.10.26
OS: Windows_NT 6.2.9200 x64
```

Have any idea how to solve this? And why am i getting this Error?

Comment: please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm

Comment: I have tried all this but still no luck

Comment: Which command you used??

Answer (score 0):

Today the Bower's current version is 1.3.8

Every time I tried to install using the `npm install bower` command on a Windows 7, but always failed.

After search the error mesage I found an issue on GitHub describing a bug on Bower installation suggesting to install an older version of Bower using `npm install -g bower@1.2.6`

I tried to install the 1.2.6 and worked.

But I don't like work with outdated version, then I uninstalled the 1.2.6 version and tried to install the latest version again and this time worked.

To resume:
1 - Try install the 1.2.6 version using `npm install -g bower@1.2.6`
2 - Uninstall Bower using 'npm uninstall -g bower'
3 - Try install the latest version using `npm install -g bower`

I hope it help