# npm is stopped working

Tags: ssl, npm

I was trying to fix SSL issue in npm by following this link
[receiving error: 'Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' while using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm)

by running this command

> sudo npm install npm -g --ca=""

after that, my npm stopped working and returning below error

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Kindly advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your "-g" corrupted your npm install.

SUGGESTION: re-install npm.

1) try `npm cache clean`

If that doesn't work, try:

2) Remove everything from ~/.npm

3) Re-install npm

Comment: thank you FoggyDay, the first step is failed because "npm" is not recognized... wondering if I could avoid re-install npm?

Comment: Q: Did you try "npm cache clean"?  Or did you just assume it wouldn't work?  Q: Did you "ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm".  It's entirely possible the "No such file or directory" error might be coming from a corrupt/incorrect script.  Q: Why can't you re-install npm?  If it's your own PC, it's quick and trivial.  If it's somebody else's server (e.g. your school's), then you should contact the system administrator.  IMHO...

Comment: thanks a lot, i followed your suggestion to reinstall it. Experienced few bumps then finally this re-install command working "sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh -L | sudo sh"