# npm node-gyp install issues on Windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, installation, npm, node-gyp

So, I don't know what was wrong before, but the solution was to uninstall Node completely and reinstall it. It came with the module already. I haven't figured out how to use it though because typing node-gyp doesn't work.

---

I am trying to install node-gyp using Node 8.1 (because I have to use this version). When I type
npm install -g node-gyp
I get the error message "SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"

I'm using npm 1.1.33, which I thought might be a problem, so I tried to upgrade using npm by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm/22099006#22099006).

```
Dallas Brittany@ZTALEI ~
$ npm config set ca ""

Dallas Brittany@ZTALEI ~
$ npm install npm -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.4.15.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.4.15.tgz
C:\Users\Dallas Brittany\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\Dallas Brittany\Ap
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@1.4.15 C:\Users\Dallas Brittany\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm

Dallas Brittany@ZTALEI ~
$ npm -v
1.1.33
```

But, as you can see, it didn't upgrade anything. So I also tried
npm install npm-latest
and got the following:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-latest
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-latest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vcsurl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: lodash@'^2.4.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.2","0.4.0","0.4.1
","0.4.2","0.5.0-rc.1","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.7.0","0.8.0","
0.8.1","0.8.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.9.2","0.10.0","1.0.0-rc.1","1.0.0-rc.2","1.0.0
-rc.3","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.3.0","1.3.1","2.0.0","
2.1.0","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.3.0","2.4.0","2.4.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\lib\cache.js:586:10)
npm ERR!     at c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:464:
15
npm ERR!     at saved (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:136:7)
npm ERR!     at c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\grac
eful-fs\graceful-fs.js:230:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR!  [Error: No compatible version found: lodash@'^2.4.1'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.2","0.4.0","0.4.1
","0.4.2","0.5.0-rc.1","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.7.0","0.8.0","
0.8.1","0.8.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.9.2","0.10.0","1.0.0-rc.1","1.0.0-rc.2","1.0.0
-rc.3","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.3.0","1.3.1","2.0.0","
2.1.0","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.3.0","2.4.0","2.4.1"]]
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files
(x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm-latest"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Dallas Brittany
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.33
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: lodash@'^2.4.1'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.2","0.4.0
","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.5.0-rc.1","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.7.0","
0.8.0","0.8.1","0.8.2","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.9.2","0.10.0","1.0.0-rc.1","1.0.0-rc.2
","1.0.0-rc.3","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.3.0","1.3.1","
2.0.0","2.1.0","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.3.0","2.4.0","2.4.1"]
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vcsurl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dallas Brittany\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to clear the cache (`npm cache clear`) and then run the command again.

Comment: When I do that, I get:
    npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Dallas Brittany\n
    de_modules\node-gyp\node_modules'
    npm ERR! error rolling back  node-gyp@0.13.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Use
    s\Dallas Brittany\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules']
    npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
    npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
    npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\Dallas Brittany\\node_modules\\
    ode-gyp\\node_modules' }
    npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: ansi@'^0.3.0'

...etc.