# Not able to install iron-router to meteor version 0.9.1

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

Today only i updated the meteor version to 0.9.1 but i am not able to install iron-router to my new project created by using the command

> meteor add iron:router

the error i get is:

```
 downloading iron:dynamic-template at version 0.3.0 ... 
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.13pjtg1++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
[Offline: Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN]
```

i also tried to revise my meteor back to older version to 0.8.3 and used mrt then also can't able to install iron-router. Please tell me how to install iron-router for meteor version 0.9.1.

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to broken pipe in connection. I was getting similar errors. Try closing the terminal window and run the update again and should run smoothly. Even if you get errors just try to run 2-3 times till all the packages are downloaded and updated.