# unable to install Mongo module using npm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am new to Node, I am trying to install the Mongo module using NPM and I am getting an error, below is the error and also the log file.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mongodb
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongodb"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!    
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, how do I attach the log file?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm

Comment: Can you use Mongoose npm? what is your business requirement for Mongodb npm?

Comment: Hi Eshwar- To be honest, I do not know the difference between the two, would you be able to point me to the differences?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with: `npm config set strict-ssl false`and then run again `npm install mongodb`

Comment: Did you run your command prompt as Admin? this error occurs mostly if you have a firewall that is blocking the cmd line installations. So run your command once as Admin. Question to you -> I generally use Mongoose. Why did you choose Mongodb? It is like the core mongo right?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason none of the solutions presented in the link did not work , becuase i just started my work I reinstalled the whole thing again an magically it got installed, Thank you everyone for looking into the question.