# How to fix Authorization Required error in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm

In node.js I was getting problems (Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN) with getting libraries, so I tried the solution from here

[receiving error: 'Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' while using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm)

which is to run

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

and now when I try to get a library, I get this:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\node
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "imagemin"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1

npm ERR! Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <HEAD><TITLE>Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
npm ERR! <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Authorization Required</H
R>
npm ERR! <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
npm ERR! Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B>
NT>
npm ERR! <HR>
npm ERR! <!-- default "Authorization Required" response (401) -->
npm ERR! </BODY>
npm ERR!




npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\Desktop\site\tools\npm-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks