# Issues installing node modules on Windows 10 machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm having an issue installing any modules onto my windows 10 machine, following a fresh nodejs install.

Its my laptop, so I have full access etc.

I have looked across numerous forums, and there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer to this issue.

The npm-debug returns the following:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'install',

1 verbose cli   '-g',

1 verbose cli   'express-generator' ]

2 info using npm@3.10.10

3 info using node@v6.10.0

4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting

5 silly install loadCurrentTree

6 silly install readGlobalPackageData

7 silly fetchPackageMetaData express-generator

8 silly fetchNamedPackageData express-generator

9 silly mapToRegistry name express-generator

10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry

11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {

12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'express-generator',

12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,

12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'express-generator',

12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'express-generator',

12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',

12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',

12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }

13 silly mapToRegistry uri (link to express generator)

14 verbose request uri (link to express generator)

15 verbose request no auth needed

16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:25:54 PM

17 verbose request id 10ea30ec4da3c14a

18 http request GET (link to express generator)

19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: write EPROTO 
101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20

19 info retry 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 9:26:05 PM

21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator

22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20

22 info retry 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 9:27:05 PM

24 http request GET (link to express generator)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:801:14)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for express-generator { Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)

25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:801:14) code: 'EPROTO', errno: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' }

26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting

27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing

28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing

29 silly install printInstalled

30 verbose stack Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20

30 verbose stack 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

30 verbose stack

30 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)

30 verbose stack     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:801:14)

31 verbose cwd C:\Users\stu\Desktop\node

32 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393

33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express-generator"

34 error node v6.10.0

35 error npm  v3.10.10

36 error code EPROTO

37 error errno EPROTO

38 error syscall write

39 error write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20

39 error 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

40 error If you need help, you may report this error at:

40 error     github issues link

41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help would be brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old version of npm (3.10.10). I'd recommend updating to the latest (as of this post - 4.4.1 stable):

```
> npm install -g npm
```

Or if the above fails:

```
> npm update -g npm
```

If you still have a problem, you can try:

```
> npm config set ca ""
```

Or (which I'd discourage but should at least confirm the problem):

```
> npm config set strict-ssl false
```

---

As a side note, much of the information you posted is irrelevant. The main problem is found near the end of the output. You seem to be having an SSL issue.

```
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20
22 info retry 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:
```

---

See: [receiving error: 'Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' while using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: After updating, I am now receiving the following errors: npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall" "-g" "express-generator"
npm ERR! node v7.7.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
npm ERR!

Comment: npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR! <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
npm ERR! <body bgcolor="white">
npm ERR! <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
npm ERR! <hr><center>nginx/1.6.3</center>
npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>

Comment: Fixed using this: npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

Comment: Thanks for your help