# Getting error while installing web-bluetooth npm in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the error i got. Please someone tell me what's this error means

> C:\Users\SVSN390\Documents>npm install web-bluetooth
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "web-bluetooth"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>   npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
>
> npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\SVSN390\Documents\npm-debug.log

Comment: Update your version of Node and NPM and see if that error still occurs :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [receiving error: 'Error: SSL Error: SELF\_SIGNED\_CERT\_IN\_CHAIN' while using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm)