Shadcn-UI throws SSL exception when trying to init
I am having the following issue, when trying to install shadcn on a React project.
npx shadcn-ui@latest init
FetchError: request to https://ui.shadcn.com/registry/styles/index.json failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/YervandM/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/125ee17d583c4e03/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  erroredSysCall: undefined
}
Failed to fetch styles from registry.

I already ran npm set strict-ssl false, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Following this thread didn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm

@ShyamMittal no it didn't. Not sure if it's related to the fact that I'm using npx. Although they should be pulling from the same registry

looks like several devs have faced it as mentioned in this issue here https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/727
